# annotated ManagedBean in Richfaces?

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm new to richfaces and I want to support a bean class using annotation instead of xml configuration [just like JSF 2.0] I'm using richfaces 4.0 and included all required jars in my build path. but when I tried to `import javax.faces.bean.*;` it through an no package found error. if I include the core JSF2.0 jar from mojarra it compiles fine but when expoted as an war file the tomcat v7 raising an error and my project fail to execute.

any help please.

P.S. without any beans, the project works well

Comment: *tomcat v7 raising an error and my project fail to execute.* Which error exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *if I include the core JSF2.0 jar from mojarra it compiles fine*

That's right. Tomcat doesn't ship with any JSF libraries out the box. RichFaces4 also doesn't ship with any particular JSF implementation. You need to have `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

---

> *but when expoted as an war file the tomcat v7 raising an error and my project fail to execute.*

You need to ensure that your `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` is declared conform JSF 2.0 spec.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"
>
    <!-- Your config here (if any) -->
</faces-config>
```

You also need to ensure that your `/WEB-INF/web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0 spec or **at least** Servlet 2.5 spec.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
>
    <!-- Your config here (if any) -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: You're welcome. In the future you should really include the error which you got. They are not for decoration only, they tell something about the cause of the problem. If you just failed in understanding the error, you should post it in your question so that we can explain them for you in layman's terms. You know, once you understand the error and thus also the cause, the solution should speak totally for itself.